# Разрешенные символы для тегов xml?

Tags: xml, теги

Какие символы можно использовать в составлении тегов xml?

Comment: Если можно (не обязательно) ссылку на документацию, где про это можно было бы прочесть

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Список разрешённых знаков для XML меток взят [отсюда](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#NT-NameStartChar):

> ":" | [A-Z] | "_" | [a-z] | [#xC0-#xD6] | [#xD8-#xF6] | [#xF8-#x2FF] |
> [#x370-#x37D] | [#x37F-#x1FFF] | [#x200C-#x200D] | [#x2070-#x218F] |
> [#x2C00-#x2FEF] | [#x3001-#xD7FF] | [#xF900-#xFDCF] | [#xFDF0-#xFFFD]
> | [#x10000-#xEFFFF]

В этот перечень входят, наверное, все языковые знаки, а вот, например, чёрточка "-", что под числом 45, в этом списке отсутствует.

Comment: То что надо! Благодарю.

Comment: Это NameStartChar, а вот в NameChar входит и чёрточка тоже